# Number of collisions of one ball between two another balls

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision

May be you know about famous problem for its answer.

> Place two billiard balls ($B_1$ and $B_2$) on the half-line $[0,\infty)$: the $B_1$ is at rest, the $B_2$ is to the right of it and is moving the left. At $x=0$ there is an elastic wall. Assume perfectly elastic collisions: the kinetic energy is preserved. How many collisions will happen depends on the masses of the ball, or rather their ratio.

For more details see [Here](https://calculus7.org/2012/03/14/galperins-billiard-method-of-computing-pi/).

---

Let me change condition of this problem a bit.

> Place two billiard balls ($B_1$ and $B_2$).
>   Both are at rest. Next, place one more ball $B_0$ between $B_1$ and $B_2$ which moves to the ball $B_2$. Every collision is elastic:
>    kinetic energy is preserved. The same question.

We can begin with simple case when masses of $B_1$ and $B_2$ are equal to $M$ and mass of $B_0$ is equal to $m$.

---

I tried to solve this and my result is a system of recurrences which 
I am not able to solve. I will post my solution below.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: How many collisions will happen?

Comment: The second problem is without a wall, right?

Comment: Yes. Just three balls.

Comment: Your title says 2 balls, but now you are asking about 3 balls. ... [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.5200.pdf) might be of some help.

Comment: It is the mathematics of this problem which is difficult, not the the physics. It is easy to calculate the velocity after each collision. The tricky part is solving the recurrence relations. That is mathematics. Try posting in Mathematics SE. You are likely to get a more authoritative response than here. But if you are not a mathematician you might not understand it. ... I have voted to leave the question open, because it is interesting.

Comment: @sammygerbil I am not asking to complete my solution but rather create some new. Maybe something like in  paper I linked in question.

Comment: @sammygerbil Firstly, I mentioned that there are 3 balls in question. Secondly, thank you for paper from its abstract I can conclude that this is exactly what I am searching for. Amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Let us introduce some notations.

### Notations

$M, m$ for mass of $B_1$ ($B_2$) and $B_0$ respectively.
$K$ for $\frac{M}{m}$
$V$ for velocity of $B_0$
$W$ for velocity of $B_1$ or $B_2$
$V_i$ for velocity of $B_0$ after $i$th collision.

---

Next, it easy to get some helpful results. But firstly note that 
answer is not depends on initial value $V_0$ of $B_0$ therefore 
without loss of generality we can assume $V_0 = 1$. So, see, fig. 
$$W_1 = \frac{2}{1+K},\quad\text{i.e. velocity of $B_2$ after 1st collision}$$
$$V_1 = \frac{1-K}{1+K},\quad\text{i.e. velosity of $B_0$ after 1st collision}$$
$$W_2 = \frac{2}{1+K}\cdot V_1,\quad\text{i.e. velocity of $B_1$ after 2nd collision}$$
$$V_2 = \Bigl(\frac{1-K}{1+K}\Bigr)^2,\quad\text{i.e. velocity of $B_0$ after 2nd collision}$$
And so on. You get the point. We can write it in general:
\begin{align}
V_{i+1} &= (V_i - W_{i-1})\frac{1-K}{1+K} + W_{i-1}\\
W_{i+1} &= (V_i - W_{i-1})\frac{2}{1+K} + W_{i-1}
\end{align}
with initial conditions
$$V_0 = 1, W_{-1} = W_0 = 0$$
That's all. Obviously, that if for some $i$ it is fulfilled that
$$|V_i| \leq |W_{i-2}|$$
then process terminated. But how to know the first such $i$. I solved these recurrences numerically and this what I have got.
[image]
Where **Theory** is 
$$f(K) = \frac{\pi\sqrt{K}}{2\sqrt{2}}.$$
Where this function comes from? In paper mentioned by @sammygebril in comments 
similar problem solved. That result is two times bigger, i.e.
$$f(K) = \frac{\pi\sqrt{K}}{\sqrt{2}},$$
for $K\gg1$.

Comment: If $K$>1, I'd rewrite the equations with $K-1$ numerators. Also in the first of your general equations, shouldn't it be $V_{i-1}$ at the end?

Comment: It does not matter because $V_i$ changes its sign from $i$ to $i$.

Comment: Sorry. I did not see your 2nd sentence in the first time. I think it shouldn't because it is convenient to look at collision from reference system where one of he balls $B_1$ or $B_2$ is at rest. That is why $W$ appears in both recurrences.